# play a multi channel streaming audio

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, react-native

i would like to know if is possible to:

- play an AAC (or another audio type) with multiple channels(from one streaming), allowing user to interact with each channel (eg.:mute, increse or decrease volume)

or

- synchronize multiple streaming to play as one single music, and allow user to 
  interact with each streaming (eg.:mute, increse or decrease volume)

I did a lot os research, and i have found a lot of solutions to play streamings (but not simultanious) or to play simultanious(but not synchronous or not streaming)

For react native i found expo libs, withh allow you to play simultaneous streaming audios, but not synchronous.
For Android native i have found SoundPool with as the same result as expo libs or exoPlayer which has more advanced options but i didn't found what i want.

I didn't research to much about iOS yet, my first focus was on react-native and android native, but anything is helpfull.